# Extract text enclosed in square brackets (with delimiter between properties within brackets)

Tags: regex, text-parsing

Original:

To keep it simple, this is what i am trying to accomplish:

**original:**

```
[category - subcategory] [some text - more text] [2018-12-31] text title here
```

**desired result:**

```
category
subcategory
some text
more text
2018-12-31
text title here
```

The number of square brackets is always the same, but the number of enclosed properties between square brackets may differ:

```
[category - subcategory] [some text - more text] [2018-12-31] text title here

[category - subcategory] [some text] [2018-12-31] text title here more text

[category] [some text - more text - even more] [2018-12-31] text title here more text
```

So text inside the first two [ ][ ] would be delimited by -

I tried my hands on regexp for the first time yesterday and it was somewhat of a headache. Is what i am trying to do possible?

Comment: You probably want to explain your "desired result" a little more, since it could currently be obtained by replacing every non alpha / space with '' (but you probably want something like `\[([^-]+)\s*-\s*([^\]]+)\]\s+\[([^-]+)\s*-\s*([^\]]+)\]\s\[([^\]]+)\]\s*(.+)`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, yet rather complicated with some expressions maybe similar to:

```
\[\s*(\s*\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*)\s*\]|(?<=\[|-)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=-|\])|([A-Za-z].*)
```

---

We would first capture the date using

```
\[\s*(\s*\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*)\s*\]
```

then other desired substrings in the other square bracket, using

```
(?<=\[|-)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=-|\])
```

and the final sentence with:

```
([A-Za-z].*)
```

for instance. We can add other chars to this char class

```
[A-Za-z]
```

if that'd be necessary.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPhO8i/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### Demo

In this demo, you can see how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /\[\s*(\s*\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*)\s*\]|(?<=\[|-)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=-|\])|([A-Za-z].*)/gm;
const str = `[category - subcategory] [some text   -   more text  ] [2018-12-31] text title here
[category - subcategory] [some text] [  2018 - 12 -31  ] text title here more text
[category] [some text - more text - even more] [2018-12-31] text title here more text
[category] [some text - more text - even more - some text - more text   -   even more  ] [2018-12-31] text title here more text`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this problem in a two-step process.

First, use this regular expression to extract the blocks between square braces and after:

```
\[(.*?)\]\s*\[(.*?)\]\s*\[(.*?)\]\s*(.*)
```

Assuming square brackets are not allowed elsewhere in the input, this will give you four group matches, for category, text, date, and free text.

Details:

- `\[` and `\]` match literal square braces.
- `(.*?)` matches text between square braces in a non-greedy way, which avoids having to use the more awkward character set `([^][]*)` to exclude them.
- `\s*` allows any number of whitespace between blocks. You can also use just one space if the pattern is always just one space.
- `(.*)` at the end will just grab everything left on the line.

Then you can split category and text on ' - ' into arrays or lists to contain the subdivisions you want. Since you want to capture a variable number of fields in the first two sets of brackets, trying to capture it all in one big regex seems more difficult than necessary when a `split()` will trivially do the job.

PS: since you didn't specify a programming language, I'm giving your descriptive pseudo-code; you'll have to lookup how to access match groups and do splitting in your language.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/coFU27/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply `sed` to get the result in your desired format

```
echo [category - subcategory] [some text - more text] [2018-12-31] text title here \
| sed -e $'s/\] /\\\n/g' -e $'s/ \- /\\\n/g' -e 's/\[//g'
```

**Output:**

```
 category
 subcategory
 some text
 more text
 2018-12-31
 text title here
```

First converting `](space)` and `(space)-(space)` to a new line then replacing `[` with `empty`

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern `\[.+?(?(?<= - ) - |\])`

Explanation:

`\[` - match `[` literally

`.+?` - match one or more of any characters (non-greedy)

`(?(?<= - ) - |\])` - conditional: if positive lookbehing `(?<= - )` (match `-` literally) is satisfied, then match `-`, else match `]` literally with `\]`

[enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/GQzLA5/1)

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and write your own parser, e.g. with `Python` (no language tagged yet?), this could be `parsimonious`:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

data = ["[category - subcategory] [some text - more text] [2018-12-31] text title here",
        "[category - subcategory] [some text] [2018-12-31] text title here more text",
        "[category] [some text - more text - even more] [2018-12-31] text title here more text",
        "[category - subcategory] [some text - more text] [2018-12-31] text title here"]


class TextVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(
        r"""
        content = (section / text)+

        section = lpar notpar (sep notpar)* rpar ws*
        text    = ~"[^][]+"

        lpar    = "["
        rpar    = "]"
        notpar  = ~"(?:(?! - )[^][])+"
        sep     = " - "
        ws      = ~"\s+"
        """
    )

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_section(self, node, visited_children):
        _, cat1, catn, *_ = visited_children

        categories = [cat1.text] + [cat[1].text for cat in catn]
        return categories

    def visit_text(self, node, visited_children):
        return [node.text]

    def visit_content(self, node, visited_children):
        result = [textnode
                  for child in visited_children
                  for subchild in child
                  for textnode in subchild]
        return result


for datapoint in data:
    tv = TextVisitor()
    result = tv.parse(datapoint)
    print("\n".join(result))
    print("###")
```

This yields

```
category
subcategory
some text
more text
2018-12-31
text title here
###
category
subcategory
some text
2018-12-31
text title here more text
###
category
some text
more text
even more
2018-12-31
text title here more text
###
category
subcategory
some text
more text
2018-12-31
text title here
###
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `\G` anchor is supported asserting the position at the end of the previous match, to get the separate parts inside the square brackets without the hyphen you might use:

```
(?:\[|\G(?!^))([^-\][\s]+(?:[ -][^-\][\s]+)*)(?: - )?(?=[^[\]]*\])
```

The matches are in the first capturing group.

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^-\][\s]+` Match 1+ any char except `-`, `]`, `[` and a whitespace char
  - `(?:[ -][^-\][\s]+)*` Repeat 0+ times same as previous pattern only prepended with space or hyphen
- `)` Close group
- `(?: - )?` Optionally match `-` between spaces
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^[\]]*\]` Match 0+ times any char except `[` and `]`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQSmTB/1)